# How to intercept browser console input with client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log

Google has an easter egg where if you search "text adventure" and then open the browser tools on the results page, you can start playing a text-based adventure game by entering words into the console:

[image]

My question is, **how does this work**?

What could they be doing that allows their JavaScript to intercept browser console input and respond accordingly?

---

Other possibly relevant details:

- Most console behavior appears to work like normal (defining variables, functions, `debugger` commands, etc.). It only behaves differently when a valid command is entered.
- You can inspect the JavaScript that contains many of the strings and logic, but it's minified so it's hard to understand much of how it works.
- It doesn't seem to be built into the browser, since the game works on Safari and Firefox.
- They aren't just intercepting errors. If you define a variable that matches their keywords (like `var yes = 'test';`), and then enter `yes` they are still able to intercept the input.

Comment: `let yes = 'no'` should break it - but a global `var` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Bergi `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'yes' has already been declared`. @bryanbraun They are identifier and not text or string, I think that's how they catch it. They don't read your input you call their predefined identifier. If you type `"yes"` it just prints yes"